# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. Cual es el problema?

Tags: python

Tengo un problema, quiero escribir en `info`, que es una lista, los valores de cada `key` del diccionario. Pero a la hora de escribir `cadena` en el archivo y luego cerrarlo con `archivo.close()`, me levanta `I/O operation on closed file`.

```
dicc={'hola':123,'chau':456}
arch=open('lista_pacientes.txt','w')
for key in dicc:
    info=str([dicc[key]])
    cadena=';'.join(info)
    arch.write(cadena +'\n')
    arch.close()
```

Comment: si alguien considera algun error a la hora de redactar la pregunta y la explicación o algo que pueda mejorar en ese sentido, agradezco las observaciones para aprender a redactar mejor :).

Comment: En la primera iteración del `for` cierras el archivo. En la segunda iteración el archivo ya está cerrado cuando intentas escribir. Saca el `close` fuera del `for`.